# Cross Community Collaboration

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

I have partner community and customer community set up for both partners and customers respectively. Business is now looking for collaboration between partners and customers (Ex: Direct messages so partners and customers work together to close a deal or go through any questions)

I see there is one idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxiuAAA) and [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwkzAAA) similar to what I am looking for.

I have also tried to post direct message using ConnectApi.FeedElement but found that this can be used only if both members are part of same community as this method expects networkId as one of the param so this also I guess is not possible for me.

Are there any ideas to overcome this limitation ? Have anyone used something other than custom (that would be my last choice)

Comment: Technical perspective: custom. Business/functional perspective from having done this before: if you were doing a deal with someone or collaborating on some task/project/etc, wouldn't you want them to be part of your "community" (quotes intentional)

Comment: Because there are already 2 communities existing and this is an enhancement in proposal for cross community collaboration.